# Fade in LI one after another, then redirect

Tags: jquery, redirect, fadein

I need to fade in a list, and then wait a few seconds and then redirect to a new page.

This is what I've gotten for the fading in after one another, which works.  How can I add a delay to the end of this, and then redirect?

```
    function fadeLi(elem) {
        elem.fadeIn(800, function() {
            fadeLi($(this).next().delay(900));
        });

    }

    fadeLi( $('#welcome li:first'));
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice recursion. This allows you to check the length of the jQuery object to detect that you have exhausted the list items.

```
function fadeLi(elem) {
    // elem is a jQuery object which support length property
    if (elem.length === 0){
        // we are out of elements so we can set the location change
        setTimeout(function(){
            // set the window location to whatever url you like
            window.location = 'https://www.where.ever/you/are/taking/the/user';
        // adjust the timeout in milliseconds
        }, 900);
        // in this case you no longer want to recursively call so return
        return;
    }
    elem.fadeIn(800, function() {
        // note: I don't think delay call has any impact here.
        fadeLi($(this).next().delay(900));
    });

}

fadeLi( $('#welcome li:first'));
```

Comment: Perfect.  I knew I had to make an if statement, just didn't convince myself hard enough.  Thank you for the help!